# Unable to checkout SVN repo using Puppet

Tags: powershell, svn, puppet, powershell-5.0

I am trying to checkout code from SVN repo for which I am accepting the URL as argument. I have quoted the URL as shown below because it contains spaces. I also checked the parameter by redirecting the `$svn_url` in file (shown below). If I pick the URL from the file and pass it *as is* on the command line to the given script, it works fine but somehow when invoked from Puppet, it's not working.

**Puppet manifests:**

`repo_checkout.pp`:

```puppet
define infra::svn::repo_checkout ($svn_url_params) {
    $svn_url = $svn_url_params[svn_url]

    include infra::params
    $repo_checkout_ps = $infra::params::repo_checkout_ps

    file { $repo_checkout_ps:
        ensure => file,
        source => 'puppet:///modules/infra/repo_checkout.ps1',
    }

    util::executeps { 'Checking out repo':
        pspath   => $repo_checkout_ps,
        argument => "\'\"$svn_url\"\'",
    }
}
```

`params.pp`:

```puppet
$repo_checkout_ps = 'c:/scripts/infra/repo_checkout.ps1',
```

`site.pp`:

```puppet
$svn_url_ad = {
    svn_url => 'https:\\\\some_repo.abc.com\svn\dir  with  space\util',
}

infra::svn::repo_checkout { "Checking out code in C:\build":
    svn_url_params => $svn_url_ad
}
```

`executeps.pp`:

```puppet
define util::executeps ($pspath, $argument) {
    $powershell = 'C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive'
    exec { "Executing PS file \"$pspath\" with argument \"$argument\"":
        command => "$powershell -file $pspath $argument",
        timeout => 900,
    }
}
```

---

**PowerShell code:**

```bsh
$svn_url = $args[0]
Set-Location C:\build
echo "svn co --username user --password xxx --non-interactive '$svn_url'" | Out-File c:\svn_url
svn co --username user --password xxx --non-interactive '$svn_url'
```

---

Puppet output on agent node:

```
Util::Executeps[Checking out repo]/Exec[Executing PS file "c:/scripts/infra/repo_checkout.ps1" with argument "'"https:\\some_repo.abc.com\svn\dir  with  space\util"'"]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: Applied catalog in 1.83 seconds
```

Content of `c:\svn_url`:

```
'https:\\\\some_repo.abc.com\svn\dir  with  space\util'
```

UPDATE: Sorry for the confusion but i was trying out several permutations and combinations and in doing that, i forgot to mention that when the `$svn_url` contains backslash `(\)`, it does *NOT* work on the command line too if i copy the SVN URL from the text file where i am redirecting the `echo` output.

Based on @Ansgar's suggestion, i changed `'$svn_url'` to `"$svn_url"` in powershell code but the output in text file then contained `'` quote *twice* around the URL. So i changed the `argument` parameter from `"\'\"$svn_url\"\'"` to `"\"$svn_url\""`. Now the output file had only single quote present around the URL. I copied only the URL (along with single quotes around it) from the output file and tried passing it to the powershell script. I now get the following error:

```
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'https:\\some_repo.abc.com\svn\dir  with  space\util'
```

Another thing to note is that if i change the back slashes in URL to forward slashes, it works *fine* on the command line. Invoking from Puppet still doesn't work.

Comment: In your PowerShell code: `'$svn_url'` -> `"$svn_url"`. Also, why the double-nested quoting in `argument => "\'\"$svn_url\"\'"`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Please check the UPDATE section.

Comment: That error might be caused by the [backslashes in your URL](https://www.tomred.net/devops/svn-error-resolving-case.html). Try changing them to forward slashes.

Comment: Thanks for the link but i have already tried forwardslashes. I use backslashes only when forward doesn't work. Unfortunately, with forwardslashes too, it's not working. Sometimes, it's really frustrating and confusing working with slashes. ;(

Comment: Sometimes it's really frustrating and confusing to work with Puppet. ;)

Comment: :D @AnsgarWiechers: Do i need to explicitly escape the dir name in the $svn_url which has spaces in it?

Comment: Seems you updated your first comment later. I used double nested quoting because the argument that i finally wanted to see getting passed to the script should have contained single quotes around the SVN URL That's because the URL has path with space in it.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I would change the URL to forward slashes, because that's what *should* work. If it doesn't you'll need to investigate that. When I need to troubleshoot stuff like that I usually insert some `notify` statements into the manifests, so I can get a better idea of where the code breaks and what values the variables actually have. I would also recommend adding quotes only at the point where they are actually required, e.g. when you actually put a variable in a commandline.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: It worked! :) Based on your last suggestion, i thought of checking it again. Although as you suggested earlier, i already tried changing `'$svn_url'` -> `"$svn_url"` and also changed `$argument` to `"\"$svn_url\""` but all this was tested with SVN URL having backslashes. I used forwardslash earlier when i started writing code but later thought of using only backslashes. Reverting to forwardslash along with your suggestions finally did the trick. :) Thanks a lot for the help! :) I'll really appreciate if you could post your suggestions as answer so i could close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the final configuration that worked out for me based on @AnsgarWiechers' suggestion.

```
[tom@pe-server] cat repo_checkout.pp
define infra::svn::repo_checkout ($svn_url_params) {
    $svn_url = $svn_url_params[svn_url]
    ...
    ...
    util::executeps { 'Checking out repo':
        pspath   => $repo_checkout_ps,
        argument => "\"$svn_url\"",
    }
}
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat repo_checkout.ps1
$svn_url = $args[0]
Set-Location C:\build
svn co --username user --password xxx --non-interactive "$svn_url"
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat params.pp
$repo_checkout_ps = 'c:/scripts/infra/repo_checkout.ps1',
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat site.pp
$svn_url_ad = {
    svn_url => 'https://some_repo.abc.com/svn/dir  with  space/util',
}
```

---

```
infra::svn::repo_checkout { "Checking out code in C:\build":
    svn_url_params => $svn_url_ad
}
```

---

Thanks a lot @AnsgarWiechers! :)

### Note:

- In **site.pp**: Used forwardslashes `(/)` when specifying `svn_url`
- In **repo_checkout.ps1**: Changed `'$svn_url'` to `"$svn_url"`
- In **repo_checkout.pp**: Changed double-nested (`'` and `"`) quoting in `argument` to single (`"`) nested i.e., from `"\'\"$svn_url\"\'"` to `"\"$svn_url\""`